# Gerar uma página em PDF utilizando Java no Back e angular no front

Tags: java, angular, mongodb, pdf, crud

Gostaria da ajuda de alguém, estou desenvolvendo um sistema utilizando Java com framework Spring Boot, e Angular no front, e gostaria de gerar um PDF com um template predefinido, somente preenchendo-o com as informações preenchidas em um CRUD simples.
Queria saber algum método que possa me auxiliar com isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você consegue fazer isso com [Itext](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer) e [Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/).

No seu controller você receberá um `HttpServletResponse` responsável pelo stream de resposta do seu PDF. Na classe que irá fazer o processamento você deverá injetar um `SpringTemplateEngine`, que no exemplo, foi atribuido à `templateEngine`.

As váriaveis serão setadas em seu template html da mesma forma que é feito com Thymeleaf.

A váriavel `nomeTemplate` é o nome do arquivo html em sua pasta /resources. Por exemplo: relatorio.html. Ele deve ser um template Thymeleaf válido!

```
    public void download(String nomeTemplate, HttpServletResponse response){
        Context context = new Context();

        Map<String, Object> variaveis = getAlgumasVariaveis();

        variaveis.forEach(context::setVariable);

        String html = templateEngine.process(nomeTemplate, context);

        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
        renderer.layout();
        try {
          renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```